# For which use cases does Array.prototype.copyWithin() exist?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, copy, in-place

It is clear, how does the method work:

```
f = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'];

console.log(f.copyWithin(4,2,5));

//  copy elements between 2 (start) & 5 (end) -> to target -> 4  

//  [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' ] <-- original array
//               ^    ^    ^
//               |    |    |                   <-- [2,5[ = c,d,e
//     0 -  1 -  2 -  3  - 4 -  5 -  6 -  7
//                         |    
//                        'c', 'd', 'e',       <-- copy to 4
//  [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',  |    |    |   'h' ] <-- replace existing elements
//  [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'h' ] <-- resulting array
```

**But, why do I need such mechanism? For which use-cases?**

Comment: One would be for a buffer, where you read data into a fixed size array, and provide chunks as lines or tokens or something. If you're close to the end of the buffer, and don't have enough data remaining for a complete chunk, you can copy that trailing data to the start of the array,  and then write more data from the source starting at the end of that previous data.

Comment: In C++ would make it sense, but not in JavaScript ?

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: like @rockstar said in buffer its a case, you can use buffers in stream scripts, download/upload file data for example if you want a use case for buffers.

Comment: @rockstar Do I have fixed size arrays in JavaScript? I can change the length of an array, whenever I want. In C++ you have to create a bigger array, copy the content etc.

Comment: @Lonely: You're right that in JS, Arrays are a dynamically sized type, but it still suffers the overhead of allocation. This avoids that. So by "fixed size", I mean you're using it as though it was fixed for efficiency.

Comment: @CiroSpaciari I don't think, that the creators of copyWithin were thinking of buffers.

Comment: @Lonely its just a use case

Comment: Maybe someone from the core-team sees this question someday and enlightens me,..

Comment: @Lonely: Why would buffers be exempted as a use case and possible motivation? And if you wanted to know what specific individuals were thinking at some point in the past, this isn't the best place to inquire.

Comment: I found an early discussion about the method. Gives little insight, but I honestly don't know what it has to do with your question since you're asking about use cases and seem  to think reusable buffers aren't relevant to JS.

Comment: I've only ever used buffers in node (https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).  I'm with @Lonely here.  *My guess* is that something about the native implementation of JS Arrays requires this method, and the act of making it public was almost zero effort.  Guessing: it was already written, all they had to do was inject it into the global scope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some of use cases and very useful to use `copyWithIn` method.

1. Implementing the `Insertion Sort Algorithm`.

```js
const insertionSort = (data, compare) => {
  const arr = [...data];
  let unsort_index = 1;

  while (unsort_index < arr.length) {

    while (arr[unsort_index] >= arr[unsort_index - 1]) unsort_index += 1;
    const pick = arr[unsort_index];

    let iter = 0;
    while (iter < unsort_index && arr[iter] < pick) iter += 1;
    arr.copyWithin(iter + 1, iter, unsort_index);
    arr[iter] = pick;

    unsort_index += 1;
  }
  return arr;
}

const input = [2, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 6, 6];
const asc = (a, b) => a - b;
const dsc = (a, b) => b - a;

console.log({ input, asc_sorted: insertionSort(input, asc) });
console.log({ input, dsc_sorted: insertionSort(input, dsc) });
```

2. Removing elements from array in place. (Checkout [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62224517/efficient-algorithm-for-removing-items-from-an-array-in-place/62275196#62275196), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62278398/how-to-remove-list-of-splices-from-array-in-javascript/62278670#62278670))

```js
function deleteItemsFromArray(array, delete_list) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    if (delete_list.includes(array[i])) {
      array.copyWithin(i, i + 1).pop();
    }
  }
}

// Alternate way, with minimal copy/move group of elements.
function deleteItemsFromArrayAlternate(array, delete_list) {
  let index = -1;
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
    if (delete_list.includes(array[i]) || !(i in array)) {
      if (index > -1) {
        array.copyWithin(index - count + 1, index + 1, i);
      }
      count += 1;
      index = i;
    }
  }
  array.length = array.length - delete_list.length;
}

const array = [9, 12, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
deleteItemsFromArray(array, [9, 6, 7]);

console.log(array);
```

3. Implementing custom encode. (Eg. Change spaces to %20 for given string in place).

```js
const myEncode = (str) => {
  const arr = [...str];
  const num_of_spaces = arr.reduce(
    (count, c) => (c === " " ? count + 1 : count),
    0
  );
  arr.length += num_of_spaces * 3;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === " ") {
      arr.copyWithin(i + 3, i + 1);
      arr[i] = "%";
      arr[i + 1] = "2";
      arr[i + 2] = "0";
    }
  }
  return arr.join("");
};

console.log(myEncode("this is some str"));
console.log(decodeURIComponent(myEncode("this is some str")));

// PS: This code can be optimised if traverse from end to start.
```

4. Rotating arrays. (Eg. left rotate by some number, right rotate by some number)

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
// rotate to [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2];

const rotate = (arr, num) => {
  arr.length += num;
  arr.copyWithin(arr.length - num, 0, num);
  arr.copyWithin(0, num);
  arr.length -= num;
};

rotate(arr, 2)
console.log(arr);
```